# Compilation error when trying to give pointer to a function to another function

Tags: library, wire-library

I'm trying to write a library for Arduino using the Wire library.
Here's my code:

PiCom.h:

```
#ifndef PiCom_h
#define PiCom_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Wire.h>
class PiCom
{
public:
    PiCom(int address, int* integers[], double* doubles[]);
    static void onReceiveCallback(int numbytes);
    static void onRequestCallback();
private:
    //Actually arrays of pointers to the data to be sent, has to be declared that way cause the size of the array isn't known at compile time
    int** _integers;
    double** _doubles;

    void onReceive(int numbytes);
    void onRequest();

    static PiCom instance;
};

#endif
```

PiCom.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "PiCom.h"


static void onReceiveCallback(int numbytes)
{

}

PiCom::PiCom(int address, int* integers[], double* doubles[])
{
    _integers = integers;
    _doubles = doubles;

    Wire.begin(address);
    void (*receiveFunction) (int);
    receiveFunction = &PiCom::onReceiveCallback;
    Wire.onReceive(receiveFunction);//Here i get an error
}
```

I want the  constructor to be created when a new instance is created. A mehtod in this object should be called when data is requested or received. When trying to pass onRequest(int) directly to Wire.onRequest(void (*) (int)) an error is thrown. Same happend when saving it to receiveFunction.

This problem was solved by using a static function (onReceiveCallback(int). I wanted this static function to call onRequest(int) in the object saved into PiCom::instance.

But now i'm getting another error:

```
PiCom\PiCom.cpp.o: In function `PiCom':
C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\PiCom/PiCom.cpp:26: undefined reference to `PiCom::onReceiveCallback(int)'
C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\PiCom/PiCom.cpp:26: undefined reference to `PiCom::onReceiveCallback(int)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer to a member function is [a painful corner of C++](http://sphaleron.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/evil-c-5-member-function-pointer.html) until C++11. This is why when you try to pass an instance method pointer to `Wire.onReceive` (without the `static` keyword), you will get an error similar to:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&PiCom::onReceiveCallback'
```

Well, you can't argue with the C++ ISO standard... changing the function to a static one (with external linkage, as they say) is indeed a workaround, as you have found out.
For this workaround to compile properly you just need to omit the `static` keyword from your **definition** (where it is implemented), and leave your **declaration** (in the header file) as is:

PiCom.h:

```
...
static void onReceiveCallback(int numbytes);
...
```

PiCom.cpp:

```
void PiCom::onReceiveCallback(int numbytes)
{
    ...
}
```

By doing this you can pass it to Wire.onReceive without any problem, from the PiCom constructor, as follows:

```
PiCom::PiCom(int address, int* integers[], double* doubles[])
{
    ...
    Wire.onReceive(&PiCom::onReceiveCallback);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Works as it should. I already noticed that i forgot the "PiCom::" and also figured out that i have to use static only in thüe declaration. But anyways, thank you for the detailed answer.